# How to exclude certain images on web page from spiders?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, duplicate-content, thumbnail

I have a page with a main image on it that I want to be indexed. I also have a list of other images (thumbnails) on the same web page that should not be indexed or associated with the current page/main image because this is the same list of thumbnails for every page on the website.

How can I stop Google from indexing this content against the page? Can I use a `Noindex, Nofollow`?

Comment: Are you making use of [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) files?

Comment: @Paul  do you mean Disallow: /thums/*.jpg ?

Comment: robots.txt can be used to block indexing of pretty much anything on a site. If that is the location of everything you want blocked, then that should work.

Comment: @Paul thank you, I will try. I hope, Google will stop navigating via thumbs and will do this via sitemaps, will not it?

Comment: I believe you can also manage what Google indexes through their [Webmasters Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/), though this will not affect other indexing services as robots.txt will.

Comment: Please go and consult Google on "robots.txt". You will find plenty of results that show you where it is and where to put it.

Comment: Do you want other bots/search engines than Google to index/crawl your images?

Comment: Sorry but there is already a vast amount of questions and answers already on Pro Webmasters regarding blocking Google from indexing pages, file extensions and folders. You can find a block all solution in the linked question, or alternatively your find various [block by file extension](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=block+file+extension) answers and questions.

Answer (score 4):

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-content/uploads/*/
```

Something like this.

Use this code in `robots.txt`, adding this, you disallow to index the folder `/wp-content/uploads/` to all crawlers.

You can found the `robots.txt` file in your `public_html` folder.

If this doesn't exist, create it :D

Comment: Thats all :P. Sorry.

Comment: Great, upvoted for the update. Just a tip for answering questions, remember, your answer should not just be a referrence for the user asking the question. This is a wiki site and your answer should be a reference for everyone visiting this page. Describe in short what your code does, how it works and most importantly, where should it be used. Many people are coming from search engine and most of them has very little to no knowledge about Wordpress.

Comment: Ok, thanks, and you right, is good to google something and found the correct answers to your problems.
Sorry for my english, i'm from Argentina!
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you want to block certain images of the main webpage then you should use Noindex and Nofollow.

Answer (score 1):

Put all your thumbnails into a specific directory that is separated from your main images:

- `/image/main/`
- `/images/thumb/`

Then add a line to your robots.txt file:

```
Disallow: /images/thumb/
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have found on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noindex):

For [Yandex](http://help.yandex.com/webmaster/?id=1127758):

```
<!--noindex-->Don't index this text.<!--/noindex-->
```

For [Yahoo](http://searchengineland.com/yahoo-supports-new-robots-nocontent-tag-to-block-indexing-within-a-page-11120):

```
<div class="robots-nocontent">Don't index this text.</div>
```

For [Google](https://developers.google.com/search-appliance/documentation/68/admin_crawl/Preparing):

```
<!--googleoff: index--> Don't index this text.<!--googleon: index-->
```

Comment: `googleoff` only works for Google Search Appliance, which is an enterprise-level search platform. It doesn't apply to Google search engine.